# parent component access child ngif condition angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component and a child component. There is a ngif statement into child component. I want to use the same ngif into the parent component.
Below is the sample code.

Child component:

```
`selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div 
          class="panel-heading" 
          (click)="opened = !opened">
          Click me
        </div>
        <div 
          class="panel-body" 
          *ngIf="opened">body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  opened = false;
  title = 'Hello Panel';
  body = 'this is the content';
}
`
parent component:
     <h3 *ngIf="loadcondition">This is Prent component</h3>
```

I tried to achieve the same with @Viewchild.
In parent.component.ts--

```
   import {ChildComponent} from './child-component';

   loadcondition : boolean = true;
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) private childreference: ChildComponent; 

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.loadcondition = this.childreference.opened= false;
       console.log('on after view init', this.childreference);
     }
```

parent.component.html--

```
<div class="center">
    <h3 *ngIf="loadcondition">This is Parent component</h3> 
    <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, childreference return undefined in the console. Is there any another way to access child conditions into parent component instead of @Viewchild.

Comment: Post what you have tried instead of posting a request. It's not really polite this way asking people to help you.

Comment: Offcourse ZF007...I tried to achieve the same with @Viewchild annotation...please refer the edited code:

Comment: Show us how you call child component inside parent component in html.

Comment: please refer edited code

Comment: Why can't you add an @input to the child? Pass in loadcondition there. It seems that the issue is that, when you put *ngIf around your child, it waits to render it since it needs to check the expression first. Plus, even if it did render, once the expression resolved to true, the child would die.